# Failed to load Hive External table from flat file in GCS environment

Tags: google-cloud-platform, hive, google-cloud-storage

I have two text file with same structure that I extracted from SQL Server. One file is 1.5gb while another is 7.5gb. I created a table in hive and then copied these files to corresponding gcs buckets. Now when I am trying to load data in tables it is failing for 7.5 gb file. After running LOAD DATA INPATH command my 7.5gb file in the bucket is getting deleted. While in case of 1.5 GB file it is working perfectly fine. What alternative way should I try to fix this issue.

My Hive QL is as below.

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myschema.mytable
( v_nbr              int,
  v_nm               varchar(80),
  p_nbr              int,
  r_nbr              int,
  a_account          varchar(80),
  a_amount           decimal(13,4),
  c_store            int,
  c_account          int,
  c_amount           decimal(13,4),
  rec_date           date)
  row format delimited 
  fields terminated by ',' 
  stored as textfile;

LOAD DATA INPATH 'gs://mybucket/myschema.db/mytable1.5/file1.5gb.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE myschema.table1.5;

LOAD DATA INPATH 'gs://mybucket/myschema.db/mytable7.5/file7.5gb.txt' OVERWRITE INTO TABLE myschema.table7.5;
```

Comment: You can use LOCATION of the file while creating the external table.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can try this:

```
CREATE EXTERNAL TABLE IF NOT EXISTS myschema.mytable
( v_nbr              int,
  v_nm               varchar(80),
  p_nbr              int,
  r_nbr              int,
  a_account          varchar(80),
  a_amount           decimal(13,4),
  c_store            int,
  c_account          int,
  c_amount           decimal(13,4),
  rec_date           date)
  row format delimited 
  fields terminated by ',' 
  stored as textfile
  LOCATION 'gs://mybucket/myschema.db/mytable1.5/file1.5gb.txt';
```